# Should we try to act in Sattva Guna or Transend Gunas?

Tags: gunas

Isn't acting in Sattva Guna not enough? Bhagavadgita (14.20) says one must transcend all Gunas. How do we transcend Gunas and why should we transcend even pure Sattva Guna?? How can we transend and how does it look like?

Comment: Well you can be Sattvik by enjoying milk, and curd. But we have to transed all desire. Even the desire of eating tasty Sattvik food.

Comment: If Gita says that one have to transcend the Gunas then why are you doubting it? I presume for you guys Gita is the ultimate authority isn't it?

Comment: @Rickross Ji, Yes Gita+Upanishads are our ultimate authority, but I am asking WHY and WHATS DIFFERENCE and How

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ramakrishna, one must transcend all gunas:

https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/parables/1_files/1-6.html

> IN THE FOREST OF THE WORLD

> Once, a man was going through a forest, when three robbers fell upon him and robbed him of all his possessions. One of the robbers said, "What's the use of keeping this man alive?" So saying, he was about to kill him with his sword, when the second robber interrupted him, saying: 'Oh, no! What is the use of killing him? Tie his hand and foot and leave him here." The robbers bound his hands and feet and went away. After a while the third robber returned and said to the man: "Ah, I am sorry. Are you hurt? I will release you from your bonds." After setting the man free, the thief said: "Come with me. I will take you to the public high way." After a long time they reached the road. At this the man said: "Sir, you have been very good to me. Come with me to my house." "Oh, no!" the robber replied. "I can't go there. The police will know it."

> This world itself is the forest. The three robbers prowling here are Satva, rajas, and lamas. It is they that rob a man of the Knowledge of Truth. Tamas wants to destroy him. „Rajas’ binds him to the world.

> But Satva rescues him from the clutches of rajas and tamas. Under the protection of Satva, man is rescued from anger, passion and other evil effects of tamas.

> Further, Satva loosens the bonds of the world. But Satva also is a robber. It cannot give man the ultimate Knowledge of Truth, though it shows him the road leading to the Supreme Abode of God. Setting him on the path, Satva tells him: "Look yonder. There is your home." Even Satva is far away from the knowledge of Brahman. (2)

Comment: Thankyou for such a nice answer sir !

Comment: Don't thank me - thank that giant of Hinduism - Ramakrishna Paramahamsa. @sethusrivatsakoduru

Comment: Please Forgive me sir - I was a bit rude to you once. I regret my foolishness

Comment: Some good-spirited give-and-take never harms anybody.  no offense taken and no forgiveness necessary @sethusrivatsakoduru

Comment: So kind of you sir!